# "bundle exec rake test" is pending

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I run `bundle exec rake test` under my application, It's pending forever. And then I entered `Ctrl-c` to stop it. Then it gives these message:

```
^C/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `gets': Interrupt
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:54:in `verify_server_version'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/run.rb:25:in `call'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ishamo/ra/sample_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/ishamo/ra/sample_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rake:3:in `load'
    from bin/rake:3:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Interrupt: 
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `system'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `block in load_schema_if_pending!'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:398:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:411:in `block in maintain_test_schema!'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:642:in `suppress_messages'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:416:in `method_missing'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:411:in `maintain_test_schema!'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/ishamo/ra/sample_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ishamo/ra/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
/home/ishamo/ra/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/ishamo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am a beginner. Would you please tell me how to do it? Appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sometimes noticed this problem myself also, where the console hangs because an issue in [Rails Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring). Spring is a Rails application preloader, designed to make developing and testing a Rails application faster.

Try running:

```
spring stop
```

or:

```
bin/spring stop
```

..and then try again.

If that doesn't help then comment out the line in your `Rakefile` that says:

```
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running 
# in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'
```

This will disable Spring altogether. Rails will start a little slower (no in-memory preloading), but you will avoid the hanging issue.

This issue seems to have been discussed previously on GitHub here:
https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/265

Comment: Oh, @Casper, thanks very much. Do as what you say solved my problem. Very much thank you.

Comment: @MoonSha Great! :) Remember to mark the answer as accepted (click the checkmark next to the answer).